# Integration tests with Spring Boot and MySQL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, integration-testing

I am familiar with Spring Data JPA and I test repositories with this kind of declaration (Spring 4):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceConfig.class})
@Sql({"classpath:it-data.sql"})
public class MyRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

So I am in charge of creating the MySQL schema and tables but the test class inserts test data (it-data.sql), and `src/test/resources/persistence.properties` contains the datasource config.

Now I want to do the same thing in a Spring Boot project. I coded a simple project that works (a Controller that uses a Service to retrieve data thanks to a Repository getting data from a MySQL database).
The problem is I am not able to code a simple test that ONLY tests a repository (I don't want to load the whole app just to test a repository), I get either context errors or datasource config errors.
Starting from

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and duplicating `src/main/resources/application.properties` to `src/test/resources/application.properties` (just changing the schema name), I tried tons of combinations using `@DataJpaTest`, `@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)`, `@Sql`, `@SpringBootTest`, `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`, `@DatabaseSetup`, etc. But nothing works.

So, knowing that I have a MySQL database that already exists for my tests, what annotations should I use to insert data into it and then test autowired repositories?
Thanks.